# Dynamic Image path in Mysql

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a MySQL database where I have a client field and another field that (hopefully) contains the URL to the image for that client. I am moving my web presence from FileMaker Pro related technologies to WordPress, and thus to the MySQL database. In FileMaker Pro I, have in a table called `filemaker_database_table_clients`, two fields called `client_name` and `photo_folder_name`, to build URLs to the photos such as this:

```
"https://www.website.com/client/" & client_name & "/" & photo_folder_name & "/" & "thumb" & "." & "jpg"
```

Is there a way to take the above URL and translate it to a field in MySQL to be used later by WordPress?

Comment: what do you mean with "translate it to a field in mysql"? fore sure both databases are in mysql

Answer (score 0):

WordPress is much more than just its database engine, MySQL.

To show your clients information in WordPress, you could first export a table containing all clients to the MySQL WordPress' database, let's call it table `clients` (with fields `client_name`, `client_photo_url`, etc.).

If you export from FileMaker to a CSV, you could then load that CSV file in MySQL, using the LOAD DATA INFILE statement. Here is an example syntax:

> LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/csv/file/filemaker_database_table_clients.csv' 
> INTO TABLE clients 
> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
> ENCLOSED BY '"' 
> LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
> IGNORE 1 ROWS;

After that you could use the information in that table to add, with a custom WordPress plugin, a single **post** (not the same but similar to what is called "a webpage" in other web technologies) per each client, including its name and a photo, among other possible client's data.

Here is an example code snippet that shows how you can use `$wpdb` and `wp_insert_post()` to accomplish this:

```
global $wpdb;
$mysql_clients_table_name = 'clients'; // The actual name of your MySQL table
$query = "SELECT * FROM $mysql_clients_table_name";
$results = $wpdb->get_results($query);
foreach ($results as $row) {
    $post_data = array(
        'post_title' => $row->client_name, // Replace this if you need a more complex title, instead of showing just the client's name
        'post_content' => ($row->client_name . '<img src="' .  $row->client_photo_url . '">') // You can add more 'content' with more data from the client (like phone_number, address, ... whatever you wish)
    );
    wp_insert_post($post_data); // Insert a new post with the data from the current row
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I have imported "clients" into a table. I found that because of another table plugin I use that I needed to import the records into the users table for the table plugin to work. Is the solution you gave entered in to SQL in Mysql?

Comment: @user3753328: The **LOAD DATA INFILE statement**, is indeed SQL to be entered into MySQL (possibly with phpMySQL), But the code snippet **global $wpdb ... wp_insert_post(...)** is a **PHP fragment** to be used as part of a Wordpress Plugin.